# How to make the overflow CSS property work with hidden as value

Tags: css, overflow, html

I am having a tough time with `overflow: hidden`.

Basically, I am trying to hide the overflow of an unordered list which is located in a `<div>`.

I have no idea why this isn't working though.

Instead of hiding it, it breaks my list from a horizontal layout to a vertical layout.

The unordered list is carousel and the container is list.

Below is my CSS code;

```
div.body .container .images {
    background: url(/images/images-background.jpg);
    height: 62px;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    width: 384px;
}
div.body .container .images #images-previous {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}
div.body .container .images #images-next {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}
div.body .container .images .list {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 336px;
}
div.body .container .images .carousel {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    width: 336px;
}
```

Here, my HTML;

```
<div class="images">
    <div id="images-previous">
        <img src="/images/images-previous.jpg" width="24" height="62" alt="Previous" />
    </div>
    <div class="list">
        <ul class="carousel">
            <li>
                <img src="/photogallery/23.jpg" width="44" height="44" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="thumbnail" />
                <img src="/images/carousel-image-holder-over.png" width="49" height="48" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="over" />
                <img src="/images/carousel-image-holder.png" width="49" height="48" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="under" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="/photogallery/23.jpg" width="44" height="44" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="thumbnail" />
                <img src="/images/carousel-image-holder-over.png" width="49" height="48" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="over" />
                <img src="/images/carousel-image-holder.png" width="49" height="48" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="under" />
            </li> 
            <li>
                <img src="/photogallery/23.jpg" width="44" height="44" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="thumbnail" />
                <img src="/images/carousel-image-holder-over.png" width="49" height="48" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="over" />
                <img src="/images/carousel-image-holder.png" width="49" height="48" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="under" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="/photogallery/23.jpg" width="44" height="44" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="thumbnail" />
                <img src="/images/carousel-image-holder-over.png" width="49" height="48" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="over" />
                <img src="/images/carousel-image-holder.png" width="49" height="48" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="under" />
            </li>    
            <li>
                <img src="/photogallery/23.jpg" width="44" height="44" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="thumbnail" />
                <img src="/images/carousel-image-holder-over.png" width="49" height="48" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="over" />
                <img src="/images/carousel-image-holder.png" width="49" height="48" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="under" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="/photogallery/23.jpg" width="44" height="44" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="thumbnail" />
                <img src="/images/carousel-image-holder-over.png" width="49" height="48" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="over" />
                <img src="/images/carousel-image-holder.png" width="49" height="48" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="under" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="/photogallery/23.jpg" width="44" height="44" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="thumbnail" />
                <img src="/images/carousel-image-holder-over.png" width="49" height="48" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="over" />
                <img src="/images/carousel-image-holder.png" width="49" height="48" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="under" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="/photogallery/23.jpg" width="44" height="44" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="thumbnail" />
                <img src="/images/carousel-image-holder-over.png" width="49" height="48" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="over" />
                <img src="/images/carousel-image-holder.png" width="49" height="48" alt="Cross Bottle 8.5" Frosted/Amber/Chain/Fleur di Lis" class="under" />
            </li>
            <!--
            <cfset i=1>
                <cfloop condition="i lte images.recordcount">
                    <cfoutput>
                        <li>
                            <img src="#images.thumburl[i]#" width="44" height="44" alt="#images.alt[i]#" class="thumbnail" />
                            <img src="/images/carousel-image-holder-over.png" width="49" height="48" alt="#images.alt[i]#" class="over" />
                            <img src="/images/carousel-image-holder.png" width="49" height="48" alt="#images.alt[i]#" class="under" />
                        </li>
                    </cfoutput>
                    <cfset i=i+1>
                </cfloop>
            </cfset>
            -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="images-next">
        <img src="/images/images-next.jpg" width="24" height="62" alt="Next" />
    </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Is there anything speaking against giving `.list` a fixed height? I think it would work then.

Comment: @Pekka, it will, i checked. Assuming that the CSS rules apply (*because the HTML posted here does not show the `div.body` and the `.container` elements*)

Comment: That didn't work. It wraps the list if the list overflows instead of hiding it.

Comment: How did your `<li>`'s get a horizontal layout? Have you missed showing us some CSS? What exactly is this for? An image slider?

Comment: Hi guys, turns out I cannot use a horizontal menu because the float or inline display will always spill because of the parent width. I am trying a table now but thats being a pain as well.

Answer (score 529, accepted):

Ok if anyone else is having this problem this may be your answer:

If you are trying to hide absolute positioned elements make sure the container of those absolute positioned elements is relatively positioned.

Comment: I had a similar problem with relatively positioned content in a container and needed the container to be relative too. So its not just hiding absolutely positioned elements, its hiding any positioned elements its looking like. :)

Comment: Actually the parent element only needs to be positioned, which means absolute and fixed are also valid. Basically anything that isn't static.

Comment: Great answer, worked for my scenario too. In my case, the div with overflow:hidden had a position:relative attribute. Adding a position:relative to its parent fixed the issue.

Answer (score 87):

Actually...

To hide an absolute positioned element, the container `position` must be anything except for `static`. It can be `relative` or `fixed` in addition to `absolute`.

Comment: To anyone else that may still be encountering this issue: the child must be `static`ally positioned, as far as I can tell. Setting `position:relative` to both the parent and child doesn't work.

Comment: dude, that was a game-changer. a `fixed` one.

Answer (score 21):

Evidently, sometimes, the display properties of ***parent*** of the element containing the matter that shouldn't overflow should ***also*** be set to `overflow:hidden` as well, e.g.:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden">
  <div style="overflow: hidden">some text that should not overflow<div>
</div>
```

Why? I have no idea but it worked for me. See https://medium.com/@crrollyson/overflow-hidden-not-working-check-the-child-element-c33ac0c4f565 (ignore the sniping at stackoverflow!)

Answer (score 9):

In addition to provided answers:

it seems like parent element (the one with `overflow:hidden`) **must not** be `display:inline`. Changing to `display:inline-block` worked for me.

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  top: 70%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<span class="outer">
  Some text
  <span class="inner"></span>
</span>
<span class="outer" style="display:inline-block;">
  Some text
  <span class="inner"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: sorry this doesn't make sense, how did you manage to have overflow with inline? also the documentation is clear : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow the overflow applies only to block container

Comment: Sure it make sense. Try having position absolute child element with negative offset. You may make such mistake with inline by default elements such as LIs and SPANs

Comment: @TemaniAfif and Miloš Đakonović .. That is correct, that `inline-block` will, or any other _block like_ display type, though in this case, where the element with `overflow: hidden` has `float`, it work also on `inline` elements.

Comment: when you add position absolute, the element become a block element so there is no inline involved here

Comment: @LGSon as per the documentation, overflow is a property that works on block level element so it cannot work on inline element. I am intresting to know how they face such case, an example would be good here

Comment: @LGSon exactly what I said .. overflow will not work because it's an inline element

Comment: @TemaniAfif He said `inline-block` will fix it...which it does, and I said, _so does `float`_ on an `inline` element, which you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/qpa5zLgc/1/

Comment: @TemaniAfif And here is an answer for your 2nd comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501300/does-position-absolute-make-that-element-a-containing-block ... and as you can see, it's more to it than to say _"add position absolute, the element become a block element"_

Comment: @TemaniAfif And do note, it is the child that got `absolute`, not the parent with `hidden` ... so the given answer is correct, though doesn't apply direct to this question since it uses `float`

Comment: @LGSon oh no, not a BoltClock answer, it give me headaches :p ... by the way, the answer should be improved with an example, because I didn't meant that the parent element will be a block element but the element itself that has the position:absolute and I thought that overflow is applied to it. So applying overflow to an initial inline element that is positionned is different from applying overflow to a simple inline element  ... because absolute = block and then the parent element is another deal. Also in the question we have no inline element, so it can create confusion.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Agree :)...still, here no other answer have sample, and I think, when stating _"**must not** be `display:inline`"_ it covers for the lack of inline elements in the question. Just think it doesn't deserve a downvote being correct.

Comment: @LGSon let's put your example then, but still not relevant to this question .. should probably be suitable in another question.

Answer (score 1):

I did not get it.
I had a similar problem but in my nav bar.

What I was doing is I kept my navBar code in this way: `nav>div.navlinks>ul>li*3>a`

In order to put hover effects on a I positioned a to relative and designed `a::before` and  `a::after` then i put a gray background on before and after elements and kept hover effects in such  way that as one hovers on `<a>` they will pop from outside a to fill `<a>`.

The problem is that the overflow hidden is not working on `<a>`.

What i discovered is if i removed `<li>` and simply put `<a>` without `<ul>` and `<li>` then it worked.

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe u could just use de inherit property of cascading by using auto instead

```
<section style="overflow: hidden">
  <section style="overflow: auto">text within overflow<div>
</section>
```

In that way, the inner section could display besides the parent elemment

Comment: In my case, I had a `<span>` element with `overflow: hidden` that was displaying the overflow way past its padding. The fix was to remove the padding from the `<span>`, wrap the `<span>` in a parent `<div>` and apply the padding to the parent `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<div style="display: flex; position: absolute; width: 100%;">
  <div style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi.
  </div>
</div>
```

Adding `position:absolute` to the parent container made it work.

PS: This is for anyone looking for a solution to dynamically truncating text.

EDIT: This was meant to be an answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267749/truncate-text-for-dynamic-width-responsive-through-css/62098228#62098228) but since they are related and it could help someone on this question I shall also leave it here instead of deleting it.