# Trim div using another div is not working

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to move a div that is inside another div so I can "Trim" the bottom part of the first div (I'm sorry if "Trim" isn't the right term for this)

`div id="ClockObj"` is inside `div id="ClockFrame"` and I want the `div id="ClockObj"` bottom part trimmed.

Anyways following this: [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#clipping), I was trying to accomplish what I want but didn't work.

Html code:

```
<div id="Main">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="85%">
                     <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="837" height="92">
                        <param name="movie" value="Flash/ReceivingHeader1.swf" />
                        <param name="quality" value="best" />
                        <param name="menu" value="true" />
                        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                        <embed 
                            src="Flash/ReceivingHeader1.swf" quality="best" menu="true" width="837" height="92" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain">
                        </embed>
                    </object>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" style="vertical-align:middle; background-color:#fff;"> 
                    <div id="ClockFrame" style="overflow:hidden;">
                        <div id="ClockObj" style="margin-top:50px;">
                            <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="139" height="77">
                                <param name="movie" value="flash/Movie_Small.swf" />
                                <param name="quality" value="best" />
                                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                                <embed src="flash/Clock_Small.swf" quality="best" menu="true" width="139" height="77" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" />
                            </object> 
                        </div>   
                    </div> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

And here the css of `div id="Main"`

```
#Main
{
    width: 980px;
    height: 550px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: solid 1px #000000; 
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #D8E4F8;
}
```

I can't have my `div id="ClockObj"` Trimmed.

What can be the problem here?

Here is what I want to achieve, but in my case with a flash movie, not a blockquote:
[image: using overflow:hidden]

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do but can I recommend you stop using tables for layout purposes. That won't fix your current issue but it will shine some light on your karmic well-being.

Comment: @SvenBieder exactly what is described in the link I posted, the part where the blockquote is clipped, but in my case I want to achieve the same thing but with a flash movie.

Comment: @Somebody I have not found an example with a block quote on the given link, but that are the specs for clipping. I can nowhere in your code see that you tried to clip something.

Comment: @SvenBieder please refer to the section `11.1.1 Overflow: the 'overflow' property` in the link: `http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#clipping` and that was what I tried to do with `div id="ClockFrame"` and `div id="ClockObj"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my question:

If you are trying to hide absolute positioned elements make sure the container of those absolute positioned elements is relatively positioned.

Credit goes to: **Darren**

[overflow: hidden not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970455/overflow-hidden-not-working)