# overflow hidden not working, position of parent relative

Tags: html, css

I want to crop images that are too tall. But "overflow: hidden" is not doing anything.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body id="index_body">
  <div id="panel">
     <div class="user_container">
       <img class="photo_thumbnail" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRRK4PrgJXJ05LYI33B5rqX4xh18UIUQ_kqplT_rXheF5bqPHrE"/>            
     </div>
     . . .
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#index_body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#panel {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
}

.user_container {
    margin: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px dashed blue;
}

.photo_thumbnail {
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px gray solid;
    width: 170px; 
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/9oLzynbx/1/.

Others have reported an issue with overflow hidden when the img it's attributed to is not in a parent div with position: relative. See: [overflow: hidden not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970455/overflow-hidden-not-working). But that's not my issue.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: delete the position:absolute;

Comment: put it on the div `.user_container` instead of the image - http://jsfiddle.net/9oLzynbx/6/

Comment: As @Pete notes the property overflow works for the container not the element that overflows http://jsfiddle.net/9oLzynbx/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the:

```
 overflow: hidden;
```

on the container: .user_container

Answer (score 1):

Give `overflow: hidden` to the `.user_container`:

```
.user_container {
    margin: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px dashed blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

#### Preview:

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/9oLzynbx/7/

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
.user_container {
    margin: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px dashed blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```