# Does position absolute make that element a containing block?

Tags: html, css, css-position

In css2.1 spec, [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#containing-block-details), there is a example explain the way how containing blocks are formed.

```
<P id="p2">This is text 
    <EM id="em1"> 
        in the
        <STRONG id="strong1">second</STRONG> 
        paragraph.
    </EM>
</P>
```

when position `em` as static, `strong`'s containing block is established by `p`,  but when position `em` as absolute, `strong`'s containing block is established by `em`.

I look through the chapter about containing block and can't find whether absolute position will form a new containing block or not. Is there something that im missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We establish that `#strong1` is a non-positioned inline box. Therefore, from the spec,

> *[...]* if the element's position is 'relative' or 'static', the containing block is formed by the content edge of the nearest block container ancestor box.

When `#em1` is not absolutely positioned, it remains an inline box. The nearest block container ancestor box to `#strong1` is `#p2`, therefore `#p2` is its containing block.

When `#em1` is absolutely positioned, it turns into a block box as shown in [section 9.7](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo). This makes it the nearest block container ancestor box to `#strong1`, therefore `#em1` becomes its containing block. A block box is [defined](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#block-boxes) as a block-level block container box.

So does absolute positioning cause an element to establish a containing block for relatively positioned or non-positioned boxes? Yes, but only when absolute positioning results in the element's box becoming the nearest block container ancestor of those boxes.

---

Note that this is a rather simplified case, since the only boxes in `#em1` are inline boxes (including the two anonymous inlines surrounding `#strong1`). Besides the fact that not all block-level boxes are block containers (tables being a common example of a block-level box that's not a block container box), even if absolute positioning *does* result in an element generating a block box, since we're talking about an inline box here, it may very well be that the inline box's block container is an anonymous block box *within* the absolutely positioned element, if that element happens to contain a mix of both block-level and inline-level boxes. This complicated case is detailed in [section 9.2.1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level).

But the complications don't stop there. The reason I say "it may very well be" is because whether or not an anonymous block box is capable of establishing a containing block isn't defined in CSS2.1.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, yes `em` with `absolute` positioning will become the new containing block. Try changing the properties in this demo:

```
p{
    //position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

em{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: yellow;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}

strong{
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xvrjve6s/