# Why left column of 2 columns has to float left to top-align?

Tags: css, layout, css-float, margin

Setting two DIVs to `width: 50%` and the first one to `float: right;`, why does the left column get laid out higher in the viewport?

[image: rendering]

```
<body>
    <div id="right" style="float: right; width: 50%;">
        <h1>Right H1 margin to div</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="left" style="width: 50%;">
        <h1>Left H1 margin to html/initial containing block</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Documentation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block describes how to identify the containing block. The default value of position is `position: static;`, so do they both have their parent DIV as the containing block? The left column extends its margin to the viewport instead of the DIV or BODY.

I see various questions asking about two-column layouts, e.g.
[What's the containing block of floated elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587518/whats-the-containing-block-of-floated-elements) .

I *can* top-justify the left and right side by `float:left` on the second `div`, but I don't understand the margins. Using the Chrome developer tools to look at the margins, I combined screenshots to produce the following two figures. First, the CSS box model for the two H1 elements.

[image: box models of the two H1 elements]

Then here is the top margin of five elements (the H1s and the DIVs and BODY as well) shown against the gray line as the top of the viewport for all five elements.

[image: Floated H1 margin not collapsed with BODY margin]

So I can see that the right H1 element (first in HTML) has a margin to the top of the BODY's content box, while the left H1 element (second in HTML) has the margin extending to the top of the viewport, collapsed with the BODY's margin maybe but also extending beyond it. Please help me understand how the specs in the docs correspond to this behavior.

Comment: you answered yourself, it's margin collapsing making the margin of the left one outside pushing all the content (including the float) to the bottom

Comment: @TemaniAfif Why doesn't the right H1 also collapse margins?

Comment: because there is no collapsing margin with float elements