# Why doesn't overflow: hidden work with div

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, css-position

I don't why I set overflow: hidden, my div is still scrollable. Pls tell me why

```
.myDiv {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Adding html structure

```
  <div className="myDiv">
     <div className='imgBx'>
        {/* img content inside */}
     </div>
     <div className='post'>
        {/* post content inside */}
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sometimes, you need to make sure that the parent element is not being scrolled. You need to provide some HTML structure so others can understand the hierarchy correctly. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970455/how-to-make-the-overflow-css-property-work-with-hidden-as-value) might help you.

Comment: I've added it, you can check out

Comment: Please provide a snippet we can run. You can pick up the actual HTML and CSS from browser dev tools inspect facility.

Comment: Ah, you’ve only given it a min height so all the content will be shown. It’ll be some parent (possibly body) that is being scrolled.

Comment: I don't get it, can you say more particularly

Comment: Even if I change the height to some specific px, it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `overflow: hidden !important;` for avoid other ovverriden styles

```
.myDiv {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: I've tried but it still doesn't work

Comment: also add height or width to .imgBx and .post class

Comment: if you want to stop scroll for inner div then you have to add on overflow: hidden !important; .imgBx and .post class

Comment: Is it necessary to set height for imgBx and post, I always set min-height: 300px

Comment: if .imgBx and .post are scrollable, then you must have to set Height & width

Comment: It's kind of hard for me to set the specific height of them because they can be added to some divs when the user use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246537/discussion-between-codenatial-developer-and-zombani).

Answer (score 0):

For allowing scroll bar.
These two CSS properties can be used to hide the scrollbars:

```
overflow-y: hidden; // hide vertical
overflow-x: hidden; // hide horizontal
```

Comment: `overflow: hidden` is equivalent to this. So for the same reason, the OP's code does not hide scrollbars, yours won't either.